# Programming webcam pan/tilt/zoom functions in C/C++ on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, webcam

I'm able to capture images from my webcam, but I want to be able to pan and tilt the camera as well as zoom the lens, but there doesn't seem to be much clear documentation on these functions and no tutorials.  Is anyone aware of some resources out there on this subject?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this really depends on your setup.  Is your camera already attached to a pan and tilt rig?

If not, check out this tutorial from Sparkfun:

http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/304

This option requires some servos, an arduino, and some code written in Processing.

Answer (score 2):

If the zoom and gimbals are already under driver control then you may be able to access them via the `VIDIOC_*_EXT_CTRLS` V4L2 ioctls; see the driver source for details.

Answer (score 1):

If the webcam follows Pelco-D/P protocol, 
just use the char string in c/c++ program and set the required bits for pan-tilt-zoom and send this string through the port. (generally USB port since serial/parallel port webcams are outdated) 
The magnitude of pan-tilt-zoom can also be adjusted.